# how to provide source Field in _msearch query in ElasticSearch 8 java client

Tags: elasticsearch

My ElasticSearch's documents are of high size. My service is Java application and its using ElasticSearch java client version 8. Need to run _msearch query on ES. MultisearchBody don't have field of _source. in ES native query I can do this by below query

```
{ "query": { "bool": { "must": { "match_all": {} } } }, "size": 10000, "_source": [ "personName" ]}
```

Not able to figure-out how to do this in ES-java client library version 8?

Answer (score 1):

In elasticsearch-java client version 8.2.0 this is not available. in version 8.8.0 this can be done by below query:

```
 var response = client.msearch(MsearchRequest.of(ms -> ms.searches(
        List.of(RequestItem.of(ri -> ri
                .header(MultisearchHeader.of(mh -> mh.index("idx_teste")))
                .body(MultisearchBody.of(msb -> msb
                    .query(MatchAllQuery.of(ma -> ma)._toQuery())
                    .source(SourceConfig.of(sc -> sc.filter(f -> f.includes(List.of("personName")))))
                    .size(10000)
                ))
            )
        ))),
        Object.class);
```